# Process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd() and extraneous newline chars

Tags: c#, windows, .net-4.0, process

I am trying to understand why, when I call the above function, I am getting hex 0D0A every 80th column on the output I am reading.

I have a powershell script, for testing that has two lines in it for brevity's sake:

```
$xmlSpew = "<IISAppPoolConfig><DefaultWebSite><ApplicationPoolName>DefaultAppPool</ApplicationPoolName></DefaultWebSite><AuthN>Basic</AuthN></IISAppPoolConfig>"
Write-Output $xmlSpew
```

I am calling the script using the Process object with ProcessStartInfo as follows:

```
var psi = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(FileToRun),
    FileName = FileToRun,
    Arguments = Arguments,
    UseShellExecute = false,
    CreateNoWindow = true,
    RedirectStandardError = true,
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
};

var process = new Process
{
    StartInfo = psi,
    EnableRaisingEvents = true,
};
```

FileToRun value is:

```
C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
```

Arguments value is:

```
-File "C:\Program Files\MyTest\MyProgInputs\read.d\IISAppPoolConfig.ps1"
```

The script runs fine and I get back exit code 0, but I have this mysterious (to me) 0D0A newline every 80th char in standard out that I capture using:

```
var Stdout = new List<string>;

...

Stdout.Add(process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
```

This is wreaking havoc on my XML efforts once I have standard out stored in a string var. I expected to get exactly what I write to the stdout in the ps1 script, not the extra newline.

What am I missing? I've looked for others with this issue, but I have not found an answer. Hopefully it is not me being search-challenged.

Comment: I should also mention that this is a 64-bit console .exe project.

Comment: Lots of things go wrong when redirecting output.  The default console is 80 characters wide.  Try the -NonInteractive command line option.  Maybe -OutputFormat XML.

Comment: -NonInteractive had no effect. -NonInteractive plus -OutputFormat XML produced encoded XML w/o the newlines, so that may be the way to go. XML after using -OutputFormat XML: #< CLIXML
<Objs Version="1.1.0.1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/2004/04"><S S="Output">&lt;IISAppPoolConfig&gt;&lt;DefaultWebSite&gt;&lt;ApplicationPoolName&gt;DefaultAppPool&lt;/ApplicationPoolName&gt;&lt;/DefaultWebSite&gt;&lt;AuthN&gt;Basic&lt;/AuthN&gt;&lt;/IISAppPoolConfig&gt;</S></Objs>

Comment: But there is still a newline after the "#< CLIXML" part of that...sigh...it should just be valid XML. *shakes fist* at powershell... ;)

Comment: Can't you just modify the scripting to write the xml to a file instead of the console?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Right now the design calls for capturing the stdout of what may be scores of scripts that are run. Tracking all those files is possible but not desirable. I really wish Write-Output would do just that and not intervene to save me from myself. I am going to look at all the other "Write-*" cmdlets and see what, if any relief I can find here.

Comment: New info...using Write-Host in the Powershell script does not produce the 0D0A char in every 80th position in the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Final and tested resolution for now (because I need to ship something), is to have output from powershell come from the Write-Host cmdlet instead of Write-Output. The process for obtaining stdout remained the same as in my original post. Hope this helps others. Thanks for all the inputs.

Answer (score 1):

Follow [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/thottams/archive/2006/08/11/696013.aspx) P/Invoke method and set `dwXCountChars` to a very large value.  Don't forget to include `STARTF_USECOUNTCHARS` in the flags as well.

Comment: When I call CreateProcess as described in the P/Invoke solution as follows (using 8 as the value for STARTF_USECOUNTCHARS) :                 CreateProcess("C:\\WINDOWS\\SYSTEM32\\WindowsPowershell\\V1.0\\powershell.exe", "-File C:\\IISAppPoolConfig.ps1", IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, false, 8, IntPtr.Zero, null, ref si, out pi);   I get a message saying "Powershell quit working". When I put 0 back in for the dwFlags part, it does not error out.  I set dwXCountChars to uint.MaxValue as well.

Comment: @JoeBaltimore - I forgot to mention `dwYCountChars`.  Set that to something like 25 or a few hundred.  Now back to `dwXCountChars`: Two gigabyte console rows might be far too wide, start from something like 30K and see if all components including your scripts can fit in that.

Comment: No change in results.  I create STARTUPINFO si = new STARTUPINFO {dwXCountChars = 200, dwYCountChars = 25};   and call CreateProcess as in my previous comment. "Powershell has stopped working".  If I call CreateProcess as follows, it does not error:                 CreateProcess("C:\\WINDOWS\\SYSTEM32\\cmd.exe",
                    "/c C:\\WINDOWS\\SYSTEM32\\WindowsPowershell\\V1.0\\powershell.exe -File \"C:\\Program Files\\rPath\\rSPU\\read.d\\IISAppPoolConfig.ps1\"",
                    IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, false, 8, IntPtr.Zero, null, ref si, out pi);
now, how to get at stdout

Comment: New info...using Write-Host in the Powershell script does not produce the 0D0A char in every 80th position in the string.

Comment: @JoeBaltimore - Congratulations.  Two ways of getting to output - either `CreatePipe` and supply the handle in `STARTUPINFO.hStdOut`, or use command redirection on `cmd.exe` command line (`> C:\mystdout.txt`)

Comment: All good, Jirka, I really appreciate your suggestions. I have tucked them into my tool belt for now.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13371/discussion-between-jirka-hanika-and-joe-baltimore)